# how to realloc inner and outer array

Tags: c, string, memory-management

So, I got a weird assignment. I have to read a file content to array string. However, I have to initialize the array like this(I have to initialize it as array size 1):

```
char **input = (char **)malloc(1*sizeof(char*))
```

instead of

```
char **input = (char **)malloc((sizeOfFile+1)*sizeof(char*))
```

So, I have to keep using realloc. My question is, how can I realloc the inner array (the string) and how can I realloc the outher array (the array of string)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to reallocate the "inner arrays". The contents of the memory you allocate is the pointers, and when you reallocate `input` then you only reallocate the `input` pointer, not the contents of where `input` points to.

---

A crude ASCII-image to show how it works:

At first when you allocate a single entry in the `input` array, it looks like this:

```
         +----------+    +---------------------------+
input -> | input[0] | -> | What `input[0]` points to |
         +----------+    +---------------------------+
```

After you reallocate to make place for a second entry (i.e. `input = realloc(input, 2 * sizeof(char*));`)

```
         +----------+    +---------------------------+
input -> | input[0] | -> | What `input[0]` points to |
         +----------+    +---------------------------+
         | input[1] | -> | What `input[1]` points to |
         +----------+    +---------------------------+
```

The contents, i.e. `input[0]` is still the same as before the reallocation. The only thing that changes is the actual `input` pointer.

Comment: So do you mean I can do something like this "input = (char**)realloc(input,previousSize+1)"

Comment: @NickStov for critical systems you may want to consider what happens to the original `input` pointer if that `realloc()` ever fails. However, for your specific purpose here, I doubt it matters much to you. Also, you need no `malloc()` for your initial `input` value, since `realloc()` will behave like `malloc()` if you pass it an initial NULL value, so just make sure `input` is NULL when this whole thing starts. (and +1 to this answer; me loves ascii art =P).

Comment: @whozcraig under what circumstances did realloc() fail? when there's not enough memory available?

Comment: @NickStov yes, at which point it returns NULL, and you just overwrote the only pointer to the previously valid allocation you had. Thus it is usually good practice to at least attempt to know it worked by storing the result in a temp, testing the temp, and only if it is non-null do you replace the original pointer (i.e. `input = temp;`). Hope that made sense.

Comment: @whozcraig okay. I will do something like that in my code :D thx

Answer (score 1):

Your `char**` (i.e. pointer to pointer to `char`) is an array of pointers that point to some memory as well. So not only that you need to allocate memory for bunch of `char*` pointers, but you also need to allocate memory that each of these pointers will point to (the memory where some characters will be stored):

```
const int ARR_SIZE = 10;
const int STR_SIZE = 20;

char** strArr = malloc(ARR_SIZE * sizeof(char*));
for (int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; ++i)
    strArr[i] = malloc(STR_SIZE * sizeof(char));

strArr[9] = "Hello";

strArr = realloc(strArr, (ARR_SIZE + 5) * sizeof(char*));
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    strArr[ARR_SIZE + i] = malloc(STR_SIZE * sizeof(char));

strArr[14] = "world!";

printf("%s %s", strArr[9], strArr[14]);
```

Full example is [here](http://ideone.com/JB3zS4). Hope this helps :)